# Running Selenium without GUI : Status code 64

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, pyvirtualdisplay

I'm trying to run Selenium in `Headless mode` in a Linux machine without GUI. The problem is that I'm getting a WebDriverException and I can't find anywhere what the `status code 64` means.

Does anyone know where to find the status code definitions ?

Code :

```py
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

path = '/home/workspace/geckodriver'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path, service_args=['--verbose', '--log-path=/tmp/firefox.log']) 

# website testing functionality: 
driver.get('https://python.org') 
print(driver.title)
```

Error :

`WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/workspace/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 64`

Comment: Had the same issue after updating Selenium to 4.0.0. After downgrading to 3.141.0 the issue is gone. If you run into "failed to decode response from marionette" after downgrading here is the Firefox, Gecko, Selenium version combo that works for me: Firefox 81, Gecko 0.26.0, Selenium 3.141.0

Comment: The latest Mozilla geckodriver is v0.30.0 and updating to that version sorted it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the status code means, but try to update the Firefox webdriver. Updating the Firefox webdriver fixed it for me.

Comment: This might have been better suited as a comment, but since you need at least 50 rep to comment, it is fine as an answer.