# I am trying to use Python Selenium to open tabs in the background and do web scraping but I keep running into this error and I don't know what to do

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.switch_to.new_window('tab')
driver.get('https://www.fbla-pbl.org/fbla-topics/')
```

the title says it all im really stuck Ive never worked with selenium so I know next to nothing any information would be extremly helpful

[image: code and error]

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198636/running-selenium-without-gui-status-code-64